# login to docker AWS registry from GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform

I would like to login to an AWS registry from my GCP instance. I have transferred the AWS ID and secret key to the instance via the GCP metadata server and can access them from my script as:

```
getMetadata() {
  curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/$1 \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
}

aws_access_key_id=`getMetadata aws_access_key_id`
aws_secret_access_key=`getMetadata aws_secret_access_key`
```

Now usually locally I can get the AWS login as:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to login to the docker registry from the shell scrip by specifying the AWS ID and the secret key through command line as it is more complicated for me to get the credentials file setup as I want during the GCP instance creation (due to the startup script running as root, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the access key and secret to AWS CLI while getting the authorization token.

```
$(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my_secret aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)
```

Comment: I get this warning" `Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.`. I think the docker login script it generates is insecure. Is there something that can be done about that?

Comment: `$(aws ecr get-login ...)` will always print out that warning.  In principle anyone on the system who can run `ps` and see your processes can get that password.  In this case, anyone who can run `docker` commands has root access on the host anyways, and the credentials that it writes out are temporary (though they do live pretty long).

Comment: You'll get the using both approach, if you want to get rid from this you can try this https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2875

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Yes, I started looking into the filed issues and it is not such a big deal for me at the moment as the instance gets killed  anyway and is not persistent. So  the risk is quiite low.